# How do I tell the Jersey Client to do the equivalent of @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) on every class it deserializes?

Tags: java, jaxb, jackson, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I have a class that I'm using the Jersey Client to deserialize.  This class has a method that looks like this:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (code == null &&
            label == null &&
            codeSystem == null &&
            codeSystemLabel == null &&
            description == null &&
            concept == null &&
            alternateCode == null
    );
```

There is no setter.  As-is, this will throw this exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "empty" (Class com.app.models.CodedElementModel), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@3b927d51; line: 1, column: 270] (through reference chain: com.app.models.LabOrderModel["code"]->com.app.models.CodedElementModel["empty"])
```

[I've read this article](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations), and it turns out I can fix this by putting this annotation on the `CodedElementModel` class: `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`.

The problem is I have a lot of methods throwing this exception.  Is there a way to configure the Jersey Client to act as if `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` is set on every class so I don't have to annotate them by hand?  I don't want to have to change ~30 files by adding this annotation manually.  This will prevent such errors in the future if someone adds a getter without a setter.

Here's how I'm creating my Jersey Client:

```
    DefaultClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
    Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
```

I feel like that `clientConfig` may have a setting to do this, but I'm not sure how to find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to configure this by instantiating and configuring the `JacksonJsonProvider` for the Jersey `Client`.

Jersey V2.x:

```
JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider = 
    new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider()
        .configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

client.register(jacksonJsonProvider);
```

Jersey V1.x:

```
DefaultClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider().
    configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
clientConfig.getSingletons().add(jacksonJsonProvider);
```

Worth noting is that the underlying issue is that your JSON contains the field "empty" ... I'm assuming it's getting there because you're serializing that same POJO. Wouldn't annotating that `isEmpty()` method to be ignored for serialization if you actually don't want it in the JSON be better?

Comment: Actually I do want it in the JSON.  That `empty` field will save people in different languages from having to write their own implementation of `isEmpty()` like my models have.

Comment: BTW, that `register` method doesn't exist on my `Client`  (maybe it's a jersey-2.0 thing?)  Do you know how to set that in jersey 1.x?

Comment: @tieTYT Yikes, sorry ... I didn't see that this was Jersey 1.x. Hang on, it's unfortunately slightly more complicated; editing

Comment: I figured it out.  It can be done like this: `clientConfig.getSingletons().add(jacksonJsonProvider);`

Comment: @tieTYT Excellent - sorry I missed that.

Comment: @BrianRoach: I took the liberty of adding the code to your answer. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted response from @sleske, didn't work for me out of the box as I'm using com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client and com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider. What actually worked for me is this ,

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();

JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
config.getSingletons().add(jacksonJsonProvider);
Client client = Client.create(config);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can also construct your custom ObjectMapper and pass it in using this.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
final JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider(mapper, JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.DEFAULT_ANNOTATIONS).configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

final Client    client  = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(jacksonJsonProvider);
```

With this maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

As documented here https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-1-x-json

Answer (score -1):

Using REST service on Client end I ran into the same problem. Here is my fix:

1) Add `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs` to your POM or include the jar in your project.

2) Modify the ClientConfig:

```
JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
jacksonJsonProvider.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
clientConfig.getClasses().add(jacksonJsonProvider.getClass());

Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
```

Comment: That won't work, and it does not make sense. You create an instance of `JacksonJsonProvider`, but never use it, except to call `getClass()` on it.